# Display Julia code output in VScode markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, markdown

I'm new to Markdown and VScode.

I would like to run my Julia code and display the output (e.g. a plot, a regression results, etc.) inside the VScode Markdown file. I am using an VS extension called "Markdown All in One".

Does anybody know how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but there's Weave.jl that takes a markdown and renders julia code inside it, adding the results to the final file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Niczky12 mentioned in the comments, the approach to doing this in Julia would be making use of: https://github.com/JunoLab/Weave.jl which provides various output formats like GitHub Markdown, HTML, PDF, etc.

This is the link to the getting started guide: http://weavejl.mpastell.com/stable/getting_started/ and Weave has support in VS Code if you are already using the Julia VS Code extension (which if you aren't, you can read more about setting up here: https://www.julia-vscode.org).